# How to remove elements of a page in htmlunit

Tags: java, dom, htmlunit

Normally in PHP, I would just parse the old document and write to the new document while ignoring the unwanted elements.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it using htmlunit classes. Well, I can, but that would probably take days. So anything you can give me for advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was the first solution I came up with:

```
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory
                                      .newInstance()
                                      .newDocumentBuilder();

            StringReader reader = new StringReader( xml );
            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(reader) );

            XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory
                                   .newInstance()
                                   .newXPath()
                                   .compile( ... );

            Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            Element el = document.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                el.removeChild( nodes.item(i) );
            }
```

As you can see it's kinda long. Being a coder who strives for simplicity, I decided to take Ahmed's advice hoping I'll find a better solution and I came up with this:

```
            List<?> elements = page.getByXPath( ... );

            DomNode node = null;
            for( Object o : elements ) {
                node = (DomNode)o;
                node.getParentNode().removeChild( node );
            }
```

Please note these are just snippets, I omitted the imports and the XPath expressions but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DOM methods, you can remove nodes.

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, I appreciate your comment. I already had a solution (see below) but your comment made me think that maybe I could find a simpler solution from the HtmlUnit API docs.

Comment: Oops, my answer went above. Sorry, newbie here.